# SQL statement to retrieve all users that have all the same values in a specific column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My POSTGRES table consists of 4 columns:

```
id  |  username  |  account #  |   active
1        john          100          true
2        amy           101          true
3        john          102          false
4        brad          103          false
5        amy           104          true
6        brad          105          false
7        brad          106          false
8        max           107          false
9        amy           108          false
```

A user can have multiple accounts that are either active or inactive. I'd like to return only users that have ONLY inactive accounts (active=false), which in this case is Brad and Max.

I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've started with the following statement that will give me the unique combinations, which I then could just return usernames with single entries but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
select username, active from table group by username ,active order by username;

username | active
john       true
john       false
amy        true
amy        false
brad       false
max        false
```

Answer (score 2):

Use having after group by:

```
    select * 
    from table
    group by table.username
    having max(users.active) = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select username
from t
group by username
having not bool_or(active);
```

If you want the accounts, you can either aggregate them:

```
select username, array_agg(account)
from t
group by username
having not bool_or(active);
```

Or use `not exists` instead:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.username = t.username and t2.active
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks! The aggregation info helped. To go a little further, is it possible to generate another column in the result where I want to do a 2nd query on another table with each of those usernames? Essentially, "select X from table2 for each of the usernames in that list  with inactive accounts"

Comment: @user1224478 . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  Perhaps you should ask a new question with more detials.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `having` clause to filter out those with only inactive accounts

```
select username
from t
group by username
having min(active)='false'and max(active)='false';
```

Another alternative using `avg`

```
select username
from t
group by username
having avg(case when active='false' then 1 else 0 end)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With aggregation and the condition in the having clause:

```
select username
from tablename
group by username
having max(active::int) = 0
```